# How to fix confirm password using reactive forms?

Tags: angular

All code is here ->

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-password-confirm-fzaajz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

What is the problem? Well the validation works great, type in the password and then confirm the password. It works great.

The case in which validation does not work is when you fill in both fields, then change the password, and then type in a good password, the mistake remains that it is not a match

Example

Type 123123 for **password**
type 123123 for **confirm password**

Again change first **password** to 123124.
Validation error is appears.

Return again to match password instead 123124 fix to 123123 it is match ... error is again here...

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="form-row px-5 py-2">
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control black-input"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        name="password"
        required
        formControlName="password"
      />
      <span
        class="error-message"
        *ngIf="
          form.controls['password'].invalid && form.controls['password'].dirty
        "
        >Password is required</span
      >
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 form-group">
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control black-input"
        id="confirmPassword"
        placeholder="Confirm Password"
        name="confirmPassword"
        required
        formControlName="confirmPassword"
      />

      <p
        class="error-message"
        *ngIf="
          (form.controls['confirmPassword'].dirty &&
            form.controls['confirmPassword'].pristine) ||
          form.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.MatchPassword
        "
      >
        Password does not match
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think it should be `form.hasError('MatchPassword ') ` instead of `form.controls['confirmPassword'].errors?.MatchPassword`, because the Validator is on the form itself.

Comment: Try in stackblitz. No work.